# Elements of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ on which a uniformly distributed random variable $X$ lives. That is, $P\{0\leq X \leq a\} = a \wedge 1$ for $ a\geq 0$.

Then, I fix a $t > 0$ and create the following $\sigma$-algebra.
$$\mathcal{G} = \sigma(1_{\{X \leq s\}}, s\leq t)$$

My question is what is a simple generator for $\mathcal{G}$?

Is the collection $A = \left(\{X\leq s\}, s\leq t\right)$ a candidate for this?

My reasoning is based on the following.

$$\{\omega: 1_{\{X(\omega) \leq s\}} = 1\} = \{\omega: X(\omega) \leq s\}$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct; the collection $A$ is a generator.

Comment: @saz Thank you for the confirmation.